# Performing a bitwise operation on all grouped by values in Presto

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, presto, trino, bitwise-or

I need to perform a `BITWISE_OR` on all grouped by values.
Say, my values in a group by are: 100, 010, and 110.  And I need to calculate "100 or 010 or 110" which is 110.

So I want to do something like: `select col1, array_agg(col2) from table group by col1`, then apply `bitwise_or` on all col2 values in the array.  There's a function `bitwise_or_agg`, but it doesn't work on an array.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

[`bitwise_or_agg(x)`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html?#bitwise_or_agg) is an aggregation function (Returns the bitwise “or” of all input values), use it instead of (or along with) array_agg:

```
select col1, 
       array_agg(col2) as my_array, 
       bitwise_or_agg(col2) as my_array_bitwise_or
  from table group by col1
```

Comment: Ahhhh!  Thanks a lot for your kind help!